# Unable to share clipboard between host and guest os

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, clipboard

I am using windows 10 as a host os.
and windows 10 on virtual box as guest os. I enabled the bidirectional sharing of clipboard on virtual box. But still I am unable to copy text from host to guest

Answer (score 0):

> I enabled the bidirectional sharing of clipboard on virtual box.

Install Guest Extensions on the guest Windows 10 machine, restart the Guest machine and then this feature should work.